# mockito testing with parameter

Tags: android, mockito

```
public void setDeviceColor(int deviceColor) {
    if (deviceColor == 0) {
        deviceColor = ColorUtil.getColorFromConte(mContext,R.color.color_1);
    }
    mDeviceColor = deviceColor;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.deviceColor);
}
```

how to test in mockito.I am unable to do it

Comment: what have you tried so far. show that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to test a method that is having arguments then you just have to  invoke that method & then verify the states & values of the class that might be changed by your method.
for eg: For a Class named TestClass your case would look like

```
@Mock
TestClass mockedTestclass;

@Test
public void testDeviceColor(){
int someDeviceColor = 123;
//invoke
mockedTestclass.setDeviceColor(someDeviceColor);
verify(mockedTestclass).notifyPropertyChanged(BR.deviceColor);
........
//other verifications
}
```

if you want to test classes having constructors with arguments then it can be easily done with JUnit. For that you have to run with Parameterized.class runner and mention the parameters in a public static method with @Paramters annotation. 
A rough example would be:

```
     @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
     class SomeTestClass{

        @Mock
        SomeTestClass mSomeTestClassInstance;

        @Parameters
        public static Object provideParameters() {
            Object[] objects =   new Object[]{
                    0,
                    0,
                    2
            };
          return objects;
        }
        public SomeTestClass(Object argument1){
        mArgument1 = argument1; 
        }

        @Test
        public void testSomeMethod{
         Object returnValue = mSomeTestClassInstance.testSomeMethod(mArgument1);
         assertequals(mArgument1,returnValue)
        }
    }
```